# How to split a text file so that each paragraph is its own file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, text-formatting

I have a long list of urls, and I'm trying to make a shell script to split each paragraph, separated by newline, into its own file. The files would need to be numbered

001
002
003
...

and so on. Here's what I tried

```
    #!/bin/zsh

    # Jakaa pitkä tiedoston kappaleet erilisiin tiedostoihin
    # Ei toimi.

    i=1
    while read p; do
        if [[ "$p" == "k" ]]; then
            i=$((i + 1))
            continue
        fi
        if (( $i < 10 )); then
            printf '%s\n' "$p" | tee -a kuvat_vol00"$i"
        elif (( $i > 9 )) && (( $i < 100 )); then
            printf '%s\n' "$p" | tee -a kuvat_vol0"$i"
        elif (( $i > 99 )); then
            printf '%s\n' "$p" | tee -a kuvat_vol"$i"
        fi
    done
```

I didn't know how to use the newline as delimiter, so that's why I use the letter 'k' instead. Stupid propably, I know...

The script works for a test file I made, something like:

```
123
k
123
k
sdfsdf
k
k
something
```

This gives me *kuvat_001* and *kuvat_002* with *"123"* and *kuvat_003* with *"sdfsdf"* and so on. But when I try it with the urls, it just prints everything to a single file *kuvat_001*. I figured it has something to do with the slashes and other funny characters in the urls. How do I make it so that the shell doesn't interpret the special characters as special? Or should I use awk or script it in vim directly or something? I just don't know how to do either of those.

I'm a little bit ashamed to ask such a stupid question, but I've struggeled with this for like three days and I can't figure it out. I completely hands down suck at shell scripting, I know, but for some reason I'm excited to learn to use the computer properly. So yeah, I appreciate any help you can give me!

EDIT:
The beginning of my input file looks like this. Can it be a problem with that?

```
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/l3Sk4TIKuKgEji-IJbxA7LetcDqWGbosjx-wSH8omLyNj4b1hq-Cs1wtFxd88XASw-FiJjjFSNbO=s1600
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/9GUUQ1HaC6m-4LbMKOZ7JLj55SqMfam9SHD6J48ezjGNY_hy8YUYYybhip_LKgYr9pKEI140Ewug=s1600
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/LYVJuq-I5kmAQUfLd_Kk28rJu1sOdo3md0ANHgS5w_wIVSIHSrwJAgO_MNm9DFg7GahrSYo4MFIp=s1600
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/qBITOIAnC09jmA-KDrFRyD3yGK_-2kNRyfr-AAJlitKTR8R7qzy8Q6v_1ukwZVBmIT8hBSRyinJE=s1600

https://2.bp.blogspot.com/9dwLT4h1pDRoOf0Mmp76zy04UGzPVEVTChNdTHAfqDPsb5fSSB2Tf4hFlFivNqPgplwKvdoEYNR0=s1600
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/D-9yBu7Zzg65mnfO2DuyU4aBcF9kAgllCJPpFuRKDrN5qUiuwJ9U-ReMhBg8b0Grg4PdcHlcmh2Y=s1600
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/RAUJka1fyc5yQAwh_O9bmqKj0vXgFvM9QvuIcKkItkxQiNFGgU1WUSBNqUQIGnnNpZaSzPHCyd8N=s1600
```

Comment: Very nearly duplicate: [How can I split a text file into multiple text files?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/46325)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with lots of tools. I would reach for awk as it has the concept of paragraphs.

```
awk '
   BEGIN { RS="" }
   { F=sprintf("kuvat_%03d", NR) ; print > F ; close(F) }' input_file_name
```

set the RS variable to the null string to active paragraph mode. 
For each record (paragraph) print it to a file of the right name and close the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's way simpler than my solution. It still prints everything to the first file though. It must be a problem with my input file since it seems to work with any other file of similar form, so I couldn't have made a typo.

Comment: Maybe the "blank" lines are not blank? If it comes from a microsoft windows environment there may be CR characters at the end of each line, or maybe there are spaces? If you have the `hexdump -C` program then 0d is the CR and 0a is the LF which is the unix end of line character (assuming ASCII of course).

Comment: Aah yes, you're right! There's a CR in front of every LF. But if I type '/\r' in Vim, it doesn't find anything. Why is that?

Comment: Ah, found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939142/replacing-carriage-return-m-with-enter). Yes, now everything makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU csplit` utility:

```
  $ csplit \
      --suppress-matched -s \
       -f kuvat_vol_ -b %03d \
        file '/^$/' '{*}'  \
  ;
```

Using `Perl`:

```
$ perl -l -00pe '
    close F if $i;
    open F, ">", sprintf "kuvat_vol_%03d", $i++;
    select F;
 ' file
```